# How to convert a document file to JSON format?

Tags: json, file-conversion

I have a WDL file of type: Microsoft Word Document. There is some metadata info in the beginning followed by some medical data. This is format of the file:

```
Ver = 1.0
ID: ABC
Type: ABC
StartTime: Jan 15,2015
EndTime: Jan 15, 2015
Main Data:
Source1 name = Name1
Source2 name = Name2
Source3 name = Name3

Method
A   B  C  D E   F
10  11 12 8 6.5 3.0
```

This is just a sample file. I have around 300 Methods in that file with different values.

I want to convert this file into JSON format. Any idea how I can achieve this? Please help. Thanks.